# Adding org to existing network fails with mismatched channel ID $CHANNEL_NAME != mychannel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Am trying to add an org to existing channle and following the steps from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html,

but at the final step for channel update

" peer channel update -f org3_update_in_envelope.pb -c $CHANNEL_NAME -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA"

It is failing with 
"Error: Invalid channel create transaction : mismatched channel ID $CHANNEL_NAME != mychannel
"

does anyoe have idea about it.

I even check the CHANNEL_NAME  vairable value and tried replacing $CHANNEL_NAME directly with mychannel as

" peer channel update -f org3_update_in_envelope.pb -c mychannel -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA"

But same error

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason,

The step to create envelope for "org3_update.json" and adding header fields to form "org3_update_in_envelope.json" has the issue

```
echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"$CHANNEL_NAME", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat org3_update.json)'}}}' | jq . > org3_update_in_envelope.json
```

here the "channel_id":"$CHANNEL_NAME" is not taken as environment variable and is actually consider as value , that's why "org3_update_in_envelope.json" file gets header "$CHANNEL_NAME" entry and not the actually channel name as mychannel

[image: org3_update_in_envelope.json created content]

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, add a single quotes around the variable like this:

```
echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"'$CHANNEL_NAME'", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat org3_update.json)'}}}' | jq . > org3_update_in_envelope.json
```

[reference this change](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/20ea5df9b871b7ca3ebeeb64c8a4ff4adaddd812#diff-e5e2bff111eed2d153a3ed85b0f9411f).